# rails console (pry) and mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, mongoid

---

I'm getting a bit confuse with the rails console.
I'm trying to connect to my database to explore the way it works.

It's all fine when I connect and do basic things like

```
#get Day database

Day.first
Day.last
Day.find('4f272afce096a47ccd000002')
```

But when I try queries like those:

http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html

This is what I get:

```
Day.where(name: "monday")
 => #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {:name=>"monday"},
  options:  {},
  class:    Day,
  embedded: false>
```

And that's when I'm lucky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a cursor-like "criteria" back. Criteria are lazily evaluated, so you can chain operations off of them. Try `Day.where(name: "monday").first`. More specifically,

"All queries in Mongoid are Criteria, which is a chainable and lazily evaluated wrapper to a MongoDB dynamic query. Criteria only touch the database when they need to, for example on iteration of the results, and when executed wrap a cursor in order to keep memory management and performance predictable." [link](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying.html)

Comment: all right, I get the idea, but quick question. I have 4 days registered in this db. Can in in some way get the 2nd, 3rd etc... in the same way that one can use first or last.

Comment: I think Mongoid criteria have a substantial subset of the interface of `Array` replicated - including the [] operator. So if you know what order your results will be in - which I believe is ordered by their `id`s by default - you can just do Day.all[0], Day.all[1], etc...